# Windows 10 not recognizing my second NVME drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, drivers, ssd, nvme

I recently installed a second NVME SSD drive and can't get Windows to recognize it.  My setup looks like this:

- System: AsRock X470 Taichi, Ryzen 5 2600X CPU
- C: - 250 GB Samsung 970
  EVO (M2_1 slot)
- D: - 2 TB Samsung 980 Pro (M2_2 slot)
- F: - 12 TB RAID 10 (4 x 6 TB SATA drives)

My Windows 10 installation is on C: and can't see the D: drive no matter what I do.  I have the Samsung NVME drivers installed and everything is up to date.  The drive doesn't show anywhere in either Disk Management or Device Manager.  I've checked Storage Spaces and there's nothing there, either.

The BIOS and multiple boot disks have no problem seeing the drive and I was even able to install a second copy of Windows to it, but the original OS still can't see it.  I'd really rather not start all over from a clean installation, any ideas?

Comment: If you boot from the second copy of Windows that you installed to it, can it see the previous disk (which will probably be named D)? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @John It's not visible to any Windows tool on the installed OS.  I've formatted using a boot disk, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, the second installation sees all the drives with no issues.  I don't see any specific difference between the two installations.  In Device Manager, it shows them both using the same standard drivers for both of the SSDs.

Comment: Maybe it's a Windows installation problem - you could try to [Do a Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) on booting from C. Note that the two M.2 slots are very different - see [link](https://linustechtips.com/topic/945713-buying-an-m2-for-taichi-x470-motherboard/) and its advice.

Comment: @harrymc I've tried repairing, but I'll try the in-place upgrade next.  I know the limitations, and I'm fine losing a PCIE slot.  I thought about trying to put the new drive in the faster slot, but I expected this way to be much easier.

Comment: @patkim Ubuntu and Hiren's Boot CD can both see and access it, so it must be a problem specific to the Windows installation.

Comment: Also do try the non destructive Windows 10 repair image commands. In command prompt as admin run `dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`    Then run `SFC /scannow`  restart and check again.

Comment: In case anyone reads this in the future: I tried every suggestion in this post, as well as many, many others and was never able to get the problem solved.  Only the new installation recognizes the drive no matter what I do, so I'll have to start from scratch with that one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to your situation, but I often get Windows not recognizing the other NVMe drive. I solve that by going to disk management and putting the second drive online. Also, if both drives have a bootable installation on them, the one that boots will destroy the boot part of the second one. I have yet to discover how to prevent that.